# how to transfer data list from one html page to another if in first page i have created a temporary list

Tags: javascript, html, transfer, datalist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXyJ8.png)
from this page i want this list to transfer it to another page in html or jsp page
i have given the code below

```
<%@page import="com.entity.prregister"%>
<%@page import="com.services.prservice"%>
<%@page import="com.connection.jdbc_connection"%>
<%@page import="com.services.regservice"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.entity.cregister"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@include file="index.jsp" %>
    <%@include file="sidebar.jsp" %>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


 <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Sale Invoice</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Advanced Form</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- SELECT2 EXAMPLE -->
        <div class="card card-default">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Add list details</h3>

            <div class="card-tools">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
                <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- /.card-header -->
          <form action="result.jsp" method="get">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Bill No</label>
                  <input type="text" name="billno" id="billno" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"></input>  
                </div>
                

                 
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Select Product</label>
                  <select name="product" id="product" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                  <label>Select HSN</label>
                  <%
                  try{ 
                      
                  prservice pr=new prservice(jdbc_connection.getconnection());
                  List<prregister> li=pr.totalList();
                  int j=0;
                  for(prregister pg:li){
                  
                  j++;
                  
                  
                  
                  %>
                 
                  
                    <option><%=pg.getPname() %></option> 
                    <option><%=pg.getHsn() %></option>
               <%
                  }
                  } catch(Exception e){
                      
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      
                  } 
               %>               
                  </select>
                </div>



               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Per/Kg</label><br>
                  <input type="text" name="perkg" id="perkg" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a date" style="width: 25%;">
               
                  <label>Quantity</label>
                  <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a date" style="width: 25%;">
               
                  <label>Rate</label>
                  <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a date" style="width: 25%;">  
               </div>                
                  
 
              </div>
              
              <!-- /.col -->

              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Bill Date</label>
                  <input type="date" name="billdate" id="billdate" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a date" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
              
              
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Select HSN</label>
                  <select name="hsn" id="hsn" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                  <label>Select HSN</label>
                  <%
                  try{ 
                      
                  prservice pr=new prservice(jdbc_connection.getconnection());
                  List<prregister> li=pr.totalList();
                  int j=0;
                  for(prregister pg:li){
                  
                  j++;
                  
                  
                  
                  %>
                 
                  
                    <option><%=pg.getPname() %></option> 
                    <option><%=pg.getHsn() %></option>
               <%
                  }
                  } catch(Exception e){
                      
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      
                  } 
               %>
               </select>
               </div>
               
               
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Submit details :</label><br>
             <input type="button" name="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary"value="Add to Cart" onclick="AddRow()">
                </div>
               </div> 
                
              </div>
             </div> 
               </form>
              <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-body -->
        </section>
        <!-- /.card -->
        
        
        
        <!--below this is code for productlist  -->
        

  <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Invoice List</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Bill No</th>                  
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>HSN</th>
                    <th>Per Kg</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Bill Date</th>
                   </tr>   
                </table>
                
                <br>
                
            <a href="result.jsp"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Bill</button></a>
              </div>
              
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
             
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
       
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
       
    </section>
  
    
        <script>
        
        var list1 = [];
        var list2 = [];
        var list3 = [];
        var list4 = [];
        var list5 = [];
        var list6 = [];
        var list7 = [];

        var n=1;
        var x=0;
        
        function AddRow(){
            
            var AddRown = document.getElementById('example2');
            var NewRow = AddRown.insertRow(n);
            
            list1[x]= document.getElementById("billno").value;
            list2[x]= document.getElementById("product").value;
            list3[x]= document.getElementById("hsn").value;
            list4[x]= document.getElementById("perkg").value;
            list5[x]= document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            list6[x]= document.getElementById("rate").value;
            list7[x]= document.getElementById("billdate").value;
            
            var cel1 = NewRow.insertCell(0);
            var cel2 = NewRow.insertCell(1);
            var cel3 = NewRow.insertCell(2);
            var cel4 = NewRow.insertCell(3);
            var cel5 = NewRow.insertCell(4);
            var cel6 = NewRow.insertCell(5);
            var cel7 = NewRow.insertCell(6);
            
            cel1.innerHTML = list1[x];
            cel2.innerHTML = list2[x];
            cel3.innerHTML = list3[x];
            cel4.innerHTML = list4[x];
            cel5.innerHTML = list5[x];
            cel6.innerHTML = list6[x];
            cel7.innerHTML = list7[x];
            
            n++;
            x++;
            
       
            
        }
        
        
        </script> 
        
             
     </div>     
</body>
</html>
```

expecting to get above list in another html page
this code creates temporary list in above page but now i need to send that to another page i really need to get this code solved